# i need list of total amount paid to a paypal recurring payment via api in php

Tags: paypal, payment-processing, paypal-subscriptions

Anybody can tell me how can i get the list of total payments made and their amount of a paypal recurring payment via api

Any will be appreciated NVP or SOAP but it should be php code
or any references

Ex-
Mr X Subscribes for a service for my magazine on my website then they will be asked for recurring payment of $450 every 6 months

after 2 years i want to list the total payment made on that profileid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [TransactionSearch API](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/transactionsearch-api-operation-nvp) and do a search for a given time frame using the email address or profile id.  This would then give you all the transactions associated with the email address, or profile id depending on what you search by.

```
<?php

/** TransactionSearch NVP example; last modified 08MAY23.
 *
 *  Search your account history for transactions that meet the criteria you specify. 
*/

$environment = 'sandbox';   // or 'beta-sandbox' or 'live'

/**
 * Send HTTP POST Request
 *
 * @param   string  The API method name
 * @param   string  The POST Message fields in &name=value pair format
 * @return  array   Parsed HTTP Response body
 */
function PPHttpPost($methodName_, $nvpStr_) {
    global $environment;

    // Set up your API credentials, PayPal end point, and API version.
    $API_UserName = urlencode('my_api_username');
    $API_Password = urlencode('my_api_password');
    $API_Signature = urlencode('my_api_signature');
    $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp";
    if("sandbox" === $environment || "beta-sandbox" === $environment) {
        $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.$environment.paypal.com/nvp";
    }
    $version = urlencode('51.0');

    // Set the curl parameters.
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

    // Turn off the server and peer verification (TrustManager Concept).
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    // Set the API operation, version, and API signature in the request.
    $nvpreq = "METHOD=$methodName_&VERSION=$version&PWD=$API_Password&USER=$API_UserName&SIGNATURE=$API_Signature$nvpStr_";

    // Set the request as a POST FIELD for curl.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

    // Get response from the server.
    $httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);

    if(!$httpResponse) {
        exit("$methodName_ failed: ".curl_error($ch).'('.curl_errno($ch).')');
    }

    // Extract the response details.
    $httpResponseAr = explode("&", $httpResponse);

    $httpParsedResponseAr = array();
    foreach ($httpResponseAr as $i => $value) {
        $tmpAr = explode("=", $value);
        if(sizeof($tmpAr) > 1) {
            $httpParsedResponseAr[$tmpAr[0]] = $tmpAr[1];
        }
    }

    if((0 == sizeof($httpParsedResponseAr)) || !array_key_exists('ACK', $httpParsedResponseAr)) {
        exit("Invalid HTTP Response for POST request($nvpreq) to $API_Endpoint.");
    }

    return $httpParsedResponseAr;
}

// Set request-specific fields.
$transactionID = urlencode('example_transaction_id');

// Add request-specific fields to the request string.
$nvpStr = "&TRANSACTIONID=$transactionID";

// Set additional request-specific fields and add them to the request string.
$startDateStr;          // in 'mm/dd/ccyy' format
$endDateStr;            // in 'mm/dd/ccyy' format
if(isset($startDateStr)) {
   $start_time = strtotime($startDateStr);
   $iso_start = date('Y-m-d\T00:00:00\Z',  $start_time);
   $nvpStr .= "&STARTDATE=$iso_start";
  }

if(isset($endDateStr)&&$endDateStr!='') {
   $end_time = strtotime($endDateStr);
   $iso_end = date('Y-m-d\T24:00:00\Z', $end_time);
   $nvpStr .= "&ENDDATE=$iso_end";
}

// Execute the API operation; see the PPHttpPost function above.
$httpParsedResponseAr = PPHttpPost('TransactionSearch', $nvpStr);

if("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"])) {
    exit('TransactionSearch Completed Successfully: '.print_r($httpParsedResponseAr, true));
} else  {
    exit('TransactionSearch failed: ' . print_r($httpParsedResponseAr, true));
}

?>
```